# Saving files with name read from text box. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, save

I have created some code that saves my work to a text file, I was just wondering is there some way so that when I click 'Save' I can read in the text from `richTextBox1`and set it as the default file name, still with the 'txt' default file extension.

e.g. When I click 'save' the folder dialog comes up and asks you to name your file, just as it would if you were using Word for example, I want that box to already have the text from my richTextBox1 in.

Thanks.

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        save.InitialDirectory = "C:\\To-Do-List";
        save.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        save.DefaultExt = ".txt";


        DialogResult result = save.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(save.FileName))
            {
                SW.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
                SW.WriteLine(richTextBox2.Text);
                SW.WriteLine(richTextBox3.Text);
                SW.WriteLine(richTextBox4.Text);
                SW.WriteLine(richTextBox5.Text);
                SW.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here.  You want to save a file from a rich text box?  Whats wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Are you asking to use the richTextBox1 value when the user doesn't specify a filename?

Comment: When I click 'save' the folder dialog comes up and asks you to name your file, just as it would if you were using Word for example, I want that box to already have the text from my richTextBox1 in. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting `save.FileName` before calling `ShowDialog` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the `FileName` property on your `SaveFileDialog`.
Add

```
save.FileName = String.Format("{0}.txt", richTextBox1.Text);
```

Before you call `ShowDialog`.